# Discriminated Union Array doesn't error on invalid keys

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, discriminated-union

I'm a little bit confused with unions of types and arrays.

I have type with the `option` key, that can takes an array. The array can be made up of a mixture of `TOption`s or `TOptionGroup`s.

```
  {
    label: "Generation 1",
    // I shouldn't be able to add 'options' + 'displayName' as they are from different types
    displayName: "This shouldn't be valid",
    options: [
      { displayName: "Bulbasaur", value: "001" },
      { displayName: "Charmander", value: "004" },
      { displayName: "Squirtle", value: "007" },
    ],
    value: "Generation 1",
  },
```

Should be impossible, but typescript isn't yelling at me - infact it's even offering autocomplete for invalid properties! I've tried adding `never` and generally playing with the type -  but I can't seem to make it strict enough.

```
type Common = {
  label?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
};

type TOption = Common & {
  value: string;
  displayName: string;
  selected?: boolean;
};

type TOptionGroup = Common & {
  options: TOption[];
};

export type Props = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  options: (TOption | TOptionGroup)[];
};


const OPTIONS: Props["options"] = [
  {
    label: "Generation 1",
    // I shouldn't be able to add 'options' + 'displayName' as they are from different types
    displayName: "This shouldn't be valid",
    options: [
      { displayName: "Bulbasaur", value: "001" },
      { displayName: "Charmander", value: "004" },
      { displayName: "Squirtle", value: "007" },
    ],
    value: "Generation 1",
  },
  {
    label: "Generation 2",
    options: [
      { displayName: "Chikorita", value: "152" },
      { displayName: "Cyndaquil", value: "155" },
      { displayName: "Totodile", value: "158" },
    ],
    value: "Generation 2",
  },
];
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdlAvFA3gKClAGwEMAjCAgfgC4oBnYAJwEsUBzAbjygBMnbSCEbtSgk4cQURScAvpxyhIUACoB5MMCaoMsRMjQAybFwBuRAgFcINeszad8vWmGIgAckQTW6jFhy605BAAxsBCImISEFKy8orQahpaKADiDHAWYDrwSNpGuPhwSai0NImaqADaALqxODgQAB5gcAzAUPFQAArpYLQ6BVAont62fg6EpOQ2vvZcRRUopVAAFOXJUAA%20KuqLaRlgAJQ1dfXBJe2qXcoAkqpuAMo0PUW0lQBEC8m079U6lVxBvhiGQCDR3ikICgIAwiIsoABGd4AGi4%20AA9OioDc6AALDIEbgoADk7TIUAE0GAcAp3G4UGJXxKxKgAGoGU4XER3CMWUR%20sBcRAQBSGNAAGbpBA8Jji8UwqHteK0NEy5yuDxecHKXF8PEEomk0TQMwEJjcFGqplLGgA-D27Bqrk8rVQd4AIQsBBI-KIFgYKKgpqs4IADKGkVAZKiHfgsE6NSNwTBcUQGAgpNwYYHg953uGACzvKMx2PxzmJ13vB4ARwsTDaghz5hDbvDAHZi9HVdVS-hc%20DIdDYfCkaXu3HVSDpm6hzC4RsAEyWh3W5Z2ssJ7mavMppgAa1aTGARGbljzCIArMuS6q41uXbuQChuEQ60wCGfW%208r5eu337XLPhnR3bU4GpXgm2RIMWwvS8AA5-x7ACB1nKF53hZdx1LIFJlBQd0JHDYAGYV3tNdbTvR0K23JM3WUMUQkPL880Xa8kNjajgMrPNlFaYJdWCFjwTYv9b04oD1VoqsAFkLG4fcmDAYS3TYxDxPtXtVVQiFCIXbRSOwwEpymME0OHfS0CLACKKgDcHUkkC6PeZR-WAAB3JhWBU95iPgzsNIch9QLdPcEAEtMfOIgBOUMOM3GjH3BLolMsZToJ0mLSMCqAtIdHS5yI7RrK4btaiAA)

Any pointers would be amazing - think I'm missing something obvious!

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: ① There are no discriminated unions in this question; just plain old unions.  Could you [edit] to fix that? ② See the linked question and answer; if you want to actually prohibit properties from other union members you should make them optional properties of type `never` (or maybe `undefined`).